# Erro ao gerar arquivo excel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-excel

Quando o sistema é executado no servidor ocorre esse erro:
ERRO:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

Tem outras sistemas no mesmo servidor que não dá erro, esse é o erro gerado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na minha maquina funciona perfeitamente, esse é o código que gera o arquivo excel:

```
protected void TESTE_GerarExcel()
        {

            #region :: GERAR ARQUIVO EXCEL ::

            var excelApp = new Excel.Application();

            excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
            Excel._Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;
            workSheet.Cells[1, "A"] = "NOME CLIENTE";
            workSheet.Cells[1, "B"] = "DESCRIÇÃO";
            workSheet.Cells[1, "C"] = "QTDE PARCELA";
            workSheet.Cells[1, "D"] = "VALOR PARCELA";
            workSheet.Cells[1, "E"] = "DATA VENCIMENTO";
            workSheet.Cells[1, "F"] = "SITUAÇÃO";
            workSheet.Cells[1, "G"] = "BOLETO ENVIADO";
            var row = 1;

            row++;
            workSheet.Cells[row, "A"] = "IND. FARMACÊUTICA";
            workSheet.Cells[row, "B"] = "ALUGUE DE SALA";
            workSheet.Cells[row, "C"] = "2";
            workSheet.Cells[row, "D"] = "200,10";
            workSheet.Cells[row, "E"] = "30/05/2016";
            workSheet.Cells[row, "F"] = "PENDENTE";
            workSheet.Cells[row, "G"] = "NÃO ENVIADO";


            workSheet.Columns[1].AutoFit();
            workSheet.Columns[2].AutoFit();
            workSheet.Columns[3].AutoFit();
            workSheet.Columns[4].AutoFit();
            workSheet.Columns[5].AutoFit();
            workSheet.Columns[6].AutoFit();
            workSheet.Columns[7].AutoFit();

            workSheet.Range["A1", "G1"].AutoFormat(Excel.XlRangeAutoFormat.xlRangeAutoFormatSimple);


            excelApp.Columns.AutoFit();

            string nome = "Contas_a_Receber_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(" ", "_").Replace("/", "_").Replace(":", "_");

            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads"), nome);

            excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(path + ".xlsx");

            #endregion

        }
```

Comment: Esse componente `Excel` não é algo nativo do asp.net, é? Talvez faltou instalar/configurar algo no servidor (que você fez na sua máquina). Se bem que a mensagem de erro indica "acesso negado". Vc tá usando um ambiente de execução similar (mesmas pastas e mesmos usuários e/ou direitos) nos dois testes?

Comment: Me parece que no servidor não tem o Excel instalado, estou aguardando uma resposta do suporte com essa confirmação, do jeito que to querendo gerar o arquivo é necessário a instalação do Excel que usa a dll `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`, preciso de alguma forma gerar o excel e salvar na máquina do usuário.

Comment: Ah, ok. Se for isso mesmo, crie você mesmo uma resposta explicando esses detalhes. :) Boa sorte! P.S.: Dependendo do conteúdo que você produz, uma alternativa que pode ser viável é você gerar um [CSV](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) (essencialmente um arquivo texto) e enviar para o usuário baixar e abrir localmente. O Excel é capaz de abrir tais arquivos.

Answer (score 1):

Evite usar a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel em projetos ASP.NET MVC. Ela depende de registro como biblioteca COM.

Em seu lugar, use a biblioteca [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/). Ela não precisa de registro COM e é bastante semelhante de usar.

[Veja aqui exemplos de uso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=epplus).